# Application is not viewing on web page after kubectl apply command

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, deployment, yaml

I am running an application called RSPM. The pod is successfully creating after kubectl apply -f <deployment-filename.yaml>. But the application is showing on web page only after I run **kubectl exec -it pod-name /bin/bash** command. Any idea why this happens? Hereby listing the YAML files.

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rspm-db-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rspm
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rspm
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: RSPM_LICENSE
          value: MY LICENSE
        image: rstudio/rstudio-package-manager:latest
        name: rstudio-package-manager
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4242
        volumeMounts:
        - name: test-config
          mountPath: /etc/rstudio-pm/
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      volumes:
      - name: test-config
        configMap:
          name: test-config
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}

---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: rstudio-pm
spec:
  selector:
    app: rspm
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 4242
    targetPort: 4242
    nodePort: 31040
  type: NodePort
```

Here's config.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-config
  labels:
    app: rspm
data:
  rstudio-pm.gcfg: |
    [Server]
    Address = http://testserver.local
    RVersion = /usr/lib64/R
    [HTTP]
    Listen = :4242
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Any thoughts https://stackoverflow.com/users/4518472/tarun-khosla?

Comment: Weird, because doesn't make any sense runs `kubectl exec` into pod to it be accessible. I think you need to review how are you build the main image, see if you missed any step in Dockefile that produce this behavior. Could you share a example image that produce the same behaviour?

Comment: I am using default image. Did not make any changes to the default image. @koopakiller

Answer (score 0):

manifest file of deployment not well formated ,you are missing - in containers , try :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rspm-db-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rspm
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rspm
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: rstudio/rstudio-package-manager:latest
        name: rstudio-package-manager
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4242
        volumeMounts:
        - name: test-config
          mountPath: /etc/rstudio-pm/
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      volumes:
      - name: test-config
        configMap:
          name: test-config
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}

---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: rstudio-pm
spec:
  selector:
    app: rspm
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 4242
    targetPort: 4242
    nodePort: 31040
  type: NodePort
```

for me the pod is not starting , i'm getting these logs in the pod :

**kubectl logs rspm-db-deployment-54f66fb6f8-k9845**

```
+ trap deactivate EXIT
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ test -f /etc/rstudio-pm/license.lic
+ unset RSPM_LICENSE
+ unset RSPM_LICENSE_SERVER
+ /opt/rstudio-pm/bin/rstudio-pm --config /etc/rstudio-pm/rstudio-pm.gcfg
2020/08/06 15:42:50 Resource limits: {"nofile":{"soft":1048576,"hard":1048576}}
2020/08/06 15:42:50 Starting RStudio Package Manager v1.1.6.1-5
2020/08/06 15:42:50 Using cache version 8
2020/08/06 15:42:50 Using metrics cache version 1
2020/08/06 15:42:50 Loading server configuration from /etc/rstudio-pm/rstudio-pm.gcfg
2020/08/06 15:42:50 Warning: clearing log region activation reloaded. Any temporary log output activation/deactivation has been reset.
2020/08/06 15:42:50 Using data directory: /var/lib/rstudio-pm
2020/08/06 15:42:50 Creating database directory: /var/lib/rstudio-pm/db
2020/08/06 15:42:50 Creating packages directory: /var/lib/rstudio-pm/packages
2020/08/06 15:42:50 Creating cran directory: /var/lib/rstudio-pm/cran
2020/08/06 15:42:50 Creating binaries directory: /var/lib/rstudio-pm/binaries
2020/08/06 15:42:50 Creating cache directory: /var/lib/rstudio-pm/cache
2020/08/06 15:42:50 Creating launcher directory: /var/lib/rstudio-pm/launcher
2020/08/06 15:42:50 Creating metrics directory: /var/lib/rstudio-pm/metrics
2020/08/06 15:42:50 Using launcher directory: /var/lib/rstudio-pm/launcher
2020/08/06 15:42:50 Creating launcher_logs directory: /var/lib/rstudio-pm/launcher/custom_logs
2020/08/06 15:42:50 Creating launcher_logs_user directory: /var/lib/rstudio-pm/launcher/custom_logs/rstudio-pm
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Updating owner to rstudio-pm for launcher directory: /var/lib/rstudio-pm/launcher
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Creating git directory: /var/lib/rstudio-pm/git
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Creating staging directory: /var/lib/rstudio-pm/packages/staging
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Using CRAN.SystemReqsRulesURL: https://rspm-sync.rstudio.com/sysreqs
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Warning: SSL is not configured. Using Package Manager over insecure HTTP is not recommended.
2020/08/06 15:42:51 A new RSPM encryption key was created at '/var/lib/rstudio-pm/rstudio-pm.key'.
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Using HTTP access log: /var/log/rstudio-pm.access.log
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Added trailing slash to the configured server address: http://testserver.local/
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Starting HTTP listener on :4242
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Starting admin service using sock file /var/run/rstudio-pm/rstudio-pm.sock
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Service ready to listen for requests
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Service mode file not found
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Starting RStudio Package Manager Services
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Starting licensing...
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Unable to obtain a valid license: Your RStudio Package Manager license has expired. Please contact your customer success representative or email sales@rstudio.com to obtain a current license.
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Unable to obtain a valid license: Your RStudio Package Manager license has expired. Please contact your customer success representative or email sales@rstudio.com to obtain a current license.
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Usage data enabled.
2020/08/06 15:42:51 R version specified in Server.RVersion cannot be analyzed: /usr/lib64/R: stat /usr/lib64/R: no such file or directory
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Stopping: metrics buffer...
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Stopping: license manager...
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Done Stopping: license manager
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Stopping: metrics janitor...
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Done Stopping: metrics janitor
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Done Stopping: metrics buffer
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Stopped RStudio Package Manager Online Services
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Error running services: Error: Unable to use R on this system: Could not locate an R installation
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Gracefully shutting down, received signal to terminate
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Stopping: signal dumper...
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Done Stopping: signal dumper
2020/08/06 15:42:51 Exited RStudio Package Manager
+ deactivate
+ echo 'Deactivating license ...'
Deactivating license ...
+ /opt/rstudio-pm/bin/license-manager deactivate
```

Comment: Yeah, the license is needed. Since it's pvt, I didnt mention in the yaml file. I added "-" and its still not working. https://stackoverflow.com/users/12260159/amar-bessalah

Comment: The only problem I am facing is, I want to run kubectl exec -it <pod name> /bin/bash to view it in the browser. It is not coming automatically when I apply the deployment file.

Comment: Updated the deployment file

Comment: what is the error you are getting if you don't do "kubeclt exec..."

Comment: It says Rstudio package manager service is not running. But when I do kubectl exec,  I can see the Rstudio package manager running.